# How can you print the contents of a text box in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Calculator(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master.geometry("1000x1000")
        self.master.title("GUI Calculator")
        self.pack()
        self.x = 0
        self.button1 = tk.Button(text = "1", fg = "Blue", bg = "Black", command = self.func1)
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2 = tk.Button(text="2", fg="Red", bg="Black", command = self.func2)
        self.button2.pack()
        self.button3 = tk.Button(text="3", fg="Green", bg="Black", command = self.func3)
        self.button3.pack()
        self.button4 = tk.Button(text="4", fg="Red", bg="Black", command = self.func4)
        self.button4.pack()
        self.button5 = tk.Button(text="5", fg="Green", bg="Black", command = self.func5)
        self.button5.pack()
        self.button6 = tk.Button(text="6", fg="Blue", bg="Black", command = self.func6)
        self.button6.pack()
        self.button7 = tk.Button(text="7", fg="Red", bg="Black", command = self.func7)
        self.button7.pack()
        self.button8 = tk.Button(text="8", fg="Green", bg="Black", command = self.func8)
        self.button8.pack()
        self.button9 = tk.Button(text="9", fg="Blue", bg="Black", command = self.func9)
        self.button9.pack()
        self.text = tk.Text(master)
        self.text.bind("<Key-Return>", self.calculation())
        self.text.pack()
        self.master.mainloop()
    def calculation(self):
        
    def func1(self):
        var1 = 1
        self.text.insert(tk.END, var1)
        self.text.pack()
    def func2(self):
        var2 = 2
        self.text.insert(tk.END, var2)
        self.text.pack()
    def func3(self):
        var3 = 3
        self.text.insert(tk.END, var3)
        self.text.pack()
    def func4(self):
        var4 = 4
        self.text.insert(tk.END, var4)
        self.text.pack()
    def func5(self):
        var5 = 5
        self.text.insert(tk.END, var5)
        self.text.pack()
    def func6(self):
        var6 = 6
        self.text.insert(tk.END, var6)
        self.text.pack()
    def func7(self):
        var7 = 7
        self.text.insert(tk.END, var7)
        self.text.pack()
    def func8(self):
        var8 = 8
        self.text.insert(tk.END, var8)
        self.text.pack()
    def func9(self):
        var9 = 9
        self.text.insert(tk.END, var9)
        self.text.pack()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Calculator()
```

I am building a calculator and want to perform a calculation based on what the user enters in the text box. But first, I have to detect what is in the text box. So, on key "enter" pressed, I wanted it to print the text box's contents. I am not sure how to do that.

I just started this project about two days ago and I got stuck so I thought I could ask on stack overflow. Thanks!

Comment: to be fair my reaction seeing your code was ... interesting (because of the repetition), the simplest way to print something from the textbox in your case would be: `print(self.text.get('1.0', 'end'))` and that would print all of it, all of what is currently in the text widget

Comment: What do you mean by "print"? Do you want to literally send it to a printer? Do you want it to appear in the terminal window? In a popup window?

Comment: also I would suggest that You have only **one** function for inserting stuff into the text widget, sth like: `def func(self, amount):` and then simply inside: `self.text.insert('end', amount)` (and you need to pack the widget only once), actually this is the most surprising thing, you are using classes but yet don't know how function/method arguments work

Comment: @BryanOakley in the terminal window

Comment: @Matiiss i tryed print(self.text.get("1.0", "end")) but it is not printing the contents on  the key enter's demand

Comment: @JiffyTec I would like to know how you tried to do that

Comment: def calculation(self):
        print(self.text.get("1.0", "end"))

Comment: and before I called calculation, this is what there is: self.text = tk.Text(master)
        self.text.bind("<Key-Return>", self.calculation())
        self.text.pack()

Comment: first of you are assigning a function call to that bind, you need to assign the function itself (basically the function name without parantheses), second you need to handle the event argument, then also you need to be focused on the text widget, and lastly it seems that the funciton is bound to any key + return key instead of just return key, I'll just write an answer I guess

Comment: @Matiiss i did not know that the "key-return" was two keys instead of just one, thanks. i am about to try what you just said

Comment: @JiffyTec: key-return is not two keys. `<Return>`, `<Key-Return>`, and `<KeyPress-Return>` are all the same thing.

Comment: why are there so many ways to bind the enter key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think @Matiiss' otherwise excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68490520/355230) went *quite* far enough in describing how to create the `Button`s. Whenever you find yourself writing a lot of repetitive code like that, it's usually a *strong* indication that there's probably a better way for you to be doing things. See the Wikipedia article on the important [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) software development principle.

In this case that's doubly-so given all those almost-identical `Button` callback functions (`func1()`, `func2()`, etc …) you've got for each one of them. The solution is to do both in single `for`-loop.

The code below illustrated how to that (and also has @Matiiss' other changes in it). Note its brevity compared to yours. I've indicated the most significant changes with `# ALL CAP COMMENTS`.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Calculator(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master.geometry("1000x1000")
        self.master.title("GUI Calculator")
        self.pack()
        self.x = 0

        # CREATE BUTTONS IN A FOR LOOP.
        btnclrs = ("Blue", "Red", "Green", "Red", "Green", "Blue", "Red", "Green", "Blue")
        self.btns = []
        for i, color in enumerate(btnclrs, start=1):
            def funcN(self=self, value=i):
                self.text.insert(tk.END, value)

            button = tk.Button(text=i, fg=color, bg="Black", command=funcN)
            button.pack()
            self.btns.append(button)

        self.text = tk.Text(self.master)
        self.text.bind("<Key-Return>", self.calculation)  # DON'T CALL FUNCTION WHEN BINDING.
        self.text.pack()
        self.text.focus_set()  # ADDED SO BOUND EVENT-HANDLERS WILL BE CALLED.
        self.master.mainloop()

    def calculation(self, event):  # ADDED event ARGUMENT.
        print(self.text.get('1.0', 'end'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Calculator()
```

Comment: Martineau and Mattiss your answers combined were very helpful indeed. My question has now been answered by both of you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: well for some reason I thought that considering what I had observed from OP's code, it would be quite a huge step for them to create buttons in a loop because usually I see people do that incorrectly, but now seeing your answer I am kind of glad that I didn't write it, so you did and therefore I learned a few things I hadn't thought about before. Also a question. Why pack the text widget again? because it gets packed once already and packing it again would not change much, is it to update the widget **similarly** to `<tkinter.Widget>.update()`(which I have read is not the best method to use)

Comment: @Matiiss: That extra `pack` call is simply an oversight — which should have been removed when I copied the OP's code. As for whether to describe how to create the buttons in a loop: I find it a fairly common conundrum here (that I coincidentally was just discussing with [another contributor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68459770/355230)). Actually I thought you *were* going to describe it in your answer…but since you didn't I decided to post something mostly as a supplement to yours.

Comment: Aahan: You're welcome. Suggestion — Create a nested `Frame` for just the buttons and use the `grid()` method inside it to lay them out in a more traditional 2D format. Also don't forget about needing to have `0` and `.` buttons.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so first about binding, this is what it should look like:

```py
self.text.bind("<Return>", self.calculation)

def calculation(event=None):
    print(self.text.get('1.0', 'end'))
```

This should now print all the contents of the text widget to terminal at the press of the return/enter key

Now suggestions, first I would suggest having only one method like this:

```py
def insert_num(self, number):
    self.text.insert('end', number)
```

and then assign to each button like this:

```py
btn1 = Button(master, text='1', command=lambda: self.insert_num(1))
```

and so for each of those buttons, just change the numbers and you only need one method (I could also suggest creating buttons in a loop but ... this should be enough for now)

EDIT: you can obviously use the `tkinter` constants for indexing, like the `tk.END` you already used

Comment: Thanks so much @Matiiss